# Update or Delete in SQL Server table based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table called `MainTable`, and I want to do two different actions (Delete Or Update) to it by joining it to a Lookup table called `LKP`.

```
MainTable                 LKP

ID                        OldID   NewID
------                    ---------------
101                       101     103
102                       102     104
103
```

I join the `MainTable` with `LKP` on `ID = OldID` to get the `NewID` for each ID.

**Delete** scenario

When the `NewID` is already in `MainTable`, then delete the `ID` in `MainTable`.

Eg. the `NewID` for 101 is 103, and 103 is already in `MainTable`, so delete 101 from `MainTable`.

**Update** scenario

When the `NewID` is not in the `MainTable`, then update the ID with the NewID.

Eg. `NewID` for 102 is 104 and 104 is not in the `MainTable`, therefore update 102 to 104.

Finally the `MainTable` should look like this:

```
ID
----
104
103
```

I tried different case statements with no luck. Please help

Comment: *"I tried different case statements with no luck. Please help"* So show us those attempts. We can't tell you what was wrong with those attempts if we don't know what they were.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `if exists` to check whether data is already available in the table or not. Based on the result you can perform further operation either `Update` or `delete`.

```
 Create procedure uspUpdateDel
 @Id int
 as
 Begin

 if exists (Select 1 from maintable join LKP on  ID = OldID where id = @Id)
 begin
   Delete from Maintable where id = @Id
 end
 else
 begin
   update Maintable set id = ... where ...
 end
End
```

Apart from the above, you can use the [@@ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check & return the number of rows involved or affected by any specific SQL Server statement as shown below and perform the action accordingly.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

UPDATE HumanResources.Employee
SET JobTitle = N'Executive'
WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';
ELSE
    PRINT 'Warning: Some rows were updated';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to perform 2 DML statements here; 1 `DELETE` and 1 `UPDATE`. As it appears that the `DELETE` has the "higher priority" then I have put that first. Otherwise this would delete the row that was updated to have a value of `103` for `ID`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MainTable (ID int);

INSERT INTO dbo.MainTable (ID)
VALUES (101),
       (102),
       (103);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.LKP (OldID int,
                      [NewID] int);

INSERT INTO dbo.LKP (OldID,
                     [NewID]) --NEWID is a function's name, I suggest a different name
VALUES (101, 103),
       (102, 104);
GO

DELETE MT
FROM dbo.MainTable MT
     JOIN dbo.LKP L ON MT.ID = L.[NewID];

UPDATE MT
SET ID = L.NewID
FROM dbo.MainTable MT
     JOIN dbo.LKP L ON MT.ID = L.OldID;

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MainTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MainTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.LKP;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Larnu, Your answer helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor over the LKP table... and do the correct action on the MainTable based on a condition.  Like this.

```
Declare 
    @oldID int, 
    @newID int;

Declare ids CURSOR
FOR Select  
        OldID, 
        NewID
    From 
        LKP;

Open ids;

Fetch Next From ids Into @oldID, @newID;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        if exists (Select 1 from MainTable where id = @newID)
        begin
            Delete from MainTable where id = @oldID
        end
        else
        begin
            update MainTable set id = @newID where id = @oldID;
        end;

        Fetch Next From ids Into @oldID, @newID;
    End;

Close ids;
Deallocate ids;
```